# How to get the orientation of hand with the help of Mediapipe?

Tags: python, mediapipe

I have a finger counting that can count 0-5. However, the result become inaccurate once the orientation of the hand is different - like when the hand is turned at 180-degree angle. To avoid this problem, I want to add to my program a function that can identify if the hand is not facing forward or at different angles.

[image: This should be the proper hand orientation that would result accurate reading]

[image: This is an example of other hand orientation that would lead to inaccurate result]

I tried to solve my issue by getting the coordinates of the middle fingertip and wrist. Then I tried to compare those coordinates to know if the hand is at a different orientation.I would like to know if there are other ways that I can do it. Or even how i can improve what I did. Thank you